# Separate logging for management commands

Tags: python, django, logging, django-manage.py

How can I configure logging in Django to use Sentry by default for all `WARNING` and higher messages, but when I run a management command lower it to `INFO` and add a console logger?

In normal operation (running the site via mod_python or uWSGI), I only care about `WARNING` and higher. However, we have some management commands that we run via cronjobs, and I would like to collect their `INFO` messages (in the management command, but also in deeper code) too in a logfile. Some of the management commands come from external libraries, I would prefer not to change them (to add extra initialization there). Ideally, I would like to detect in the settings module whether we are running via `manage.py` or via WSGI.

The relevant part of my current `LOGGING` dict:

```
    'root': {
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'handlers': ['sentry'],
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        }.
        'sentry': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'class': 'raven.contrib.django.handlers.SentryHandler',
        },
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

A very crude way: modify `manage.py` to add something in the environment, and detect this in the settings module.

In `manage.py`:

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_IS_MANAGEMENT_COMMAND'] = '1'
```

In the settings module:

```
if os.environ.get('DJANGO_IS_MANAGEMENT_COMMAND', False):
    LOGGING['root']['level'] = 'INFO'
    LOGGING['root']['handlers'].append('console')
```

This will also add the logger when running Celery workers, but I think the daemon has no stdout, so it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use different settings for management commands `./manage.py my_task --settings=proj.settings.management`, right? So you can just override the logging section and "inherit" the rest from your original settings file... Or am I missing some point in your question?

Comment: That would be possible indeed, but then I would need to remember to add this every time. I was looking for a simple way to detect Django was started via `manage.py` vs. another way (most likely WSGI).